# Is it possible to export a font as base64 using xslt?

Tags: css, xslt, fonts, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I want to create some html output from `.fo` file and I wrote myself some xsl templates to get the desired output.
For the styling of the `html`-elements, each element has a `class` attribute with the matching `css`-class.

That looks like the following:

```css
.page_2_text_3 {
   transform: translate(0pt, 82.96pt);
   font-family: ITCFranklinGothicStd-Book;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-variant: normal;
   font-size: 10pt;
   color: #000000;
}
```

The problem here is that the font `ITCFranklinGothicStd-Book` can't be found and is substituted by some other font.

Is there any way to export the font as base64 in a template, so i can add a `@font-face` to my css like so:

```xml
<xsl:template name="fontexport">
  <xsl:param name="font"/>
  <xsl:param name="fontname"/>
  @font-face {
   font-family: "<xsl:value-of select="$fontname"/>";
   src: url("<xsl:value-of select="$font" mode="base64"/>")<!-- convert the $font into base64 -->
  }
</xsl:template>
```

this should create the following output when calling `call-template` with font and fontname as parameter

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: "ITCFranklinGothicStd-Book";
   src: url("data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAB...)
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Does your HTML user agent/renderer support that `@font-face { src: uri("data:...") }` CSS property with a `data` URI having base64 encoded font data? In terms of XSLT, to base64 encode data and to read a (font) file, you need to look into extension like EXPath file and bin module, probably. The commercial editions of Saxon support those, I think, the open-source HE not. You could nevertheless delegate the task to Java, either outside of XSLT or with an integrated extension function.

Comment: I use apache fop currently in version 2.3. I have `saxon9he.jar` in my lib folder.

Comment: Integrated extension functions for Saxon 9.9 are documented in https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/extensibility/integratedfunctions/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move to an XSLT processor that supports the EXPath file module, such as Saxon-PE, then you can read the font file using `file:read-binary()`, which returns an `xs:base64Binary` value, and the `string()` function applied to this value gives you the Base64 representation.

Comment: Does Apache FOP support it?

Comment: @CrazyEight, I would think that Apache FOP works with the commercial versions of Saxon the same as with the HE version, by dropping the relevant Saxon jar in the lib folder of fop. You need acquire a license of Saxon PE or EE if you want to run it, so make sure you request an evaluation license from Saxonica to test https://www.saxonica.com/download/download.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I might give this a try later but first of all i am fine with just adding the manually transformed base64 fonts by myself.